# How do I calculate average in my field calculator within specified limit?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, statistics

I would like to calculate the average, max and min of each trips that I have. Each trips are also predefined (e.g. Trip 1, Trip 2) in the attribute table. (As below). I have more than 2000 trips.

The question I have is - how do I calculate the average, max and min speed for each trips? Do I use the field calculator? If so, how do I type my command?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a dissolve on Trip, then in the Statistics Field(s) just add the fields and the statistic type you want to be added to the attribute table.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm

This has the added benefit of keeping the geometries for your data.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) tool:

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `summarize` tool on the field `Trip`, and in the summary statistics, select the relevant fields to calculate statistics for, like ave, min, max etc.

[image]

The result is a table with a row for each trip, and a column for each statistic.